# How can I Convert grayscale image to false color gradient with imagemagick

Tags: colors, imagemagick, grayscale, palette, indexed

[input b/w, output with CLUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49bWj.jpg)

I want to create false color images from grayscale input images. Similar to the typical false color images produced by nasa from b/w inputs to highlight contrast and texture. I can do this in gimp by applying a custom gradient to an indexed color b/w photo. I am sure there is a way to duplicate this with IM but, i cannot find an example in the docs or on stackoverflow. My goal is to automate the process and produce several pseudocolor outputs from each b/w input image. This is for an art project, so no great precision or scientific validity is required. Although, someone may build on my project.

An example would be producing a color relief map from a typical bump map.

Your solution worked. Thank you @MarkSetchell

## create new colour look up table named rainbowCLUT.png:

```
convert -size 1x1! xc:black xc:red xc:orange xc:yellow xc:green xc:blue xc:violet xc:white +append -resize 255x1! rainbowCLUT.png
```

## apply clut to image:

```
convert FullMoon2010.jpg rainbowCLUT.png -clut result.png;eog result.png
```

Comment: Have a look here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/37387232/2836621

Comment: And here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/36825769/2836621

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you @MarkSetchell

#create new colour look up table named rainbowCLUT.png

convert -size 1x1! xc:black xc:red xc:orange xc:yellow xc:green xc:blue xc:violet xc:white +append -resize 255x1! rainbowCLUT.png

#apply clut to image
</p>
convert FullMoon2010.jpg rainbowCLUT.png -clut result.png;eog result.png

Comment: Excellent! Not sure what shade you wanted for your green, but you might find you like **ImageMagick** `lime` rather than `green`.

Comment: Great Job Mark! @Molly, please post your solution as an answer, and mark it as accepted. It'll help future readers know this question was resolved with Mark's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution worked. Thank you @MarkSetchell

create new colour look up table named rainbowCLUT.png:

```
convert -size 1x1! xc:black xc:red xc:orange xc:yellow xc:green xc:blue xc:violet xc:white +append -resize 255x1! rainbowCLUT.png
```

apply clut to image:

```
convert FullMoon2010.jpg rainbowCLUT.png -clut result.png;eog result.png
```